# Android - отследить изменение размера ScrollView

Tags: android, admob, android-scrollview

В моём приложении используется автоматическая прокрутка ScrollView в конец, но прокрутка сбрасывается сразу после прогрузки баннера AdMob.

Прокрутка сразу после задания текста выгледит так:

```java
private void прокрутить_до_конца() {
        прокрутка.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                прокрутка.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN); //Прокручиваем вывод консоли до конца.
            }
        });
    }
```

Методы показа баннеров находятся в [родительском классе](https://github.com/sashaqwert/ArenaControl/blob/54f3209205442add3c1bd5be2c924417a1b524f9/app/src/main/java/ru/sccraft/arenacontrol/ADsActivity.java):

```java
private void показать_рекламу() {
        adView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        String AD_DATA = fe.getFile("appname-ads");
        if (AD_DATA.contains("1")) return; //Для повышения вероятности работы покупки. Раньше использовался equals.
        MobileAds.initialize(this, getString(R.string.admob_appid));
        adView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().setRequestAgent("android_studio:ad_template").build();
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
    }

    protected final void задать_баннер(AdView баннер) {
        this.adView = баннер;
        показать_рекламу();
    }
```

XML разметка:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="ru.sccraft.arenacontrol.ConsoleActivity">

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id"></com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/console_cmd"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/console_send"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Command"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/console_send"
        style="@android:style/Widget.Material.ImageButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:onClick="send"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_send" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/console_scrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/console_cmd"
        android:layout_below="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/console_textView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textIsSelectable="true"
                tools:text="Line1\nLine2\nLine3" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Java код Activity целиком [здесь](https://github.com/sashaqwert/ArenaControl/blob/54f3209205442add3c1bd5be2c924417a1b524f9/app/src/main/java/ru/sccraft/arenacontrol/ConsoleActivity.java)

Для того, чтобы восстановить прокрутку мне нужно отследить изменение размера AdView или ScrollView. Как это сделать?

Comment: Попробуйте к корневому элементы добавить вот это: `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"`

Comment: @ЮрийСПб В таком случае не видно последнее 1-3 строки. Приходится прокручивать их пользователю вручную.

Comment: А если прокручивать так: `scrollView.scrollTo (0, Integer.MAX_VALUE)`?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Если без `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"`, то в ScrolView ничего нет, пока не прокрутишь сам.
Если с `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"`, тоже самое...

Comment: Если предложенное не сработало, то попробуйте таки вашем предполагаемым способом сделать. Для получения размеров вьюх надо `OnGlobalLayoutListener` использовать: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Этот метод помог, но теперь нельзя вводить текст в EditText под ScrollView из-за постоянно слетающего фокуса.
Дописывание `editText.requestFocus()` в `onGlobalLayout()` не помогает.

Comment: А что, если после успешного скрола после прогрузки рекламы отключать OnGlobalLayoutListener?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95337/discussion-between-sashaqwert-and-).

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Дело в том, что я не знаю, как отловить момент полной прогрузки рекламы.

Comment: По идее у AdView есть колбэк на это (https://developers.google.com/admob/android/banner?hl=en). Либо можно попробовать отключать OnGlobalLayoutListener после нужного срабатывания. Тут не уверен, первое это будет или нет. Если нет - возможно можно нужное вычислить по к-л параметрам, типа высоты AdView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Отследить изменение размера ScrollView в этом конкретном случае можно через отслеживание момента прогрузки рекламы в AdView.

Это можно сделать через **AdListener**, установленный на AdView. Этот код добавляется сразу после метода `задать_баннер()`

```
adView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded() {
                // Code to be executed when an ad finishes loading.
                //Выполняется после прогрузки рекламы
                прокрутить_до_конца(); //Выполнить прокрутку ScrollView в конец
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
                // Code to be executed when an ad request fails.
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdOpened() {
                // Code to be executed when an ad opens an overlay that
                // covers the screen.
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdClicked() {
                // Code to be executed when the user clicks on an ad.
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdLeftApplication() {
                // Code to be executed when the user has left the app.
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdClosed() {
                // Code to be executed when the user is about to return
                // to the app after tapping on an ad.
            }

        });
```

То есть прокрутка выполнится сразу после прогрузки рекламы. Пользователю ничего не понадобится докручивать.